# seo friendly url in php using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I 'm fighting with htaccess XD, but I can not find the fault, because i don´t know much about htaccess, i have set the correct settings in the phpinfo file.

My no seo link:

```
<a href="proyecto?id=<?php echo $id_proyecto . '&title=' . $url; ?>">
```

Examples browser:
mydomain.com/proyecto.php?id=1&title=diseno-desarrollo-web

My question is how can I convert this link SEO Friendly

This is my htaccess file on raiz, but it don´t work.

```
#Whitout PHP

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^proyecto/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/\.]+)/?$ proyecto?id=$1title=$2 [L]
```

thanks in advance

Comment: How are the input paths supposed to look like? What should `$1` and `$2` originate from? Why not rewrite to `proyecto.php` directly?

Comment: my knowledge is zero in .htaccess, can you show me a example white rewrite directly to proyecto.php. My httpd.conf is active the LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Comment: What do you want the final uri to look like?

Comment: Like this: mydomain.com/proyecto/1/diseno-desarrollo-web

Comment: If you don't know how those rules work, read some references first: [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20563772)

Comment: Thanxs for the reference page, i will look it.

Answer (score 4):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^proyecto/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /proyecto.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

and add the following at the bottom

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: thanxs for the example @Vigikaran, but i have delete my htaccess file and introduced the example and it didn´t change nothing in the browser :(, tested in localhost and in my server. I do not know why